# If True Statements in Bash

Tags: bash, aws-cli

I am trying to run a command using the AWS CLI and then set the output of that command to a variable, which was easy enough. I parsed the initial command with jq and the output was an array of the GroupNames which is exactly what I wanted. Now I am trying to run an if statement that says if $1 is in the list_groups: print the users in that group. My issue is two fold. I do not know if The output from the first command is readable because it is not in a specific format.

```
#!/bin/bash


list_groups=$(aws iam list-groups --output json | jq -r .'Groups[] | .GroupName' --output json)
echo $list_groups

if ${1} == $list_groups;
then
echo aws iam get-group --group-name $1 --output json

else 
echo 'sorry'
fi
```

So I am trying to take the list_groups variable that I stored the output of that CLI command in and then with user input in $1 see if what I input is in that GroupName and if it is use that $1 to then print out the users inside that group show in the command below.

```
echo aws iam get-group --group-name $1 --output json
```

I am sorry as I cannot print my output here for the GroupNames I am getting back from the first command as it is sensitive but, here is an example.

```
Admin Users assets.dev assets.prod
```

As you can see there are no separating values and I am not sure if that is contributing to the issues.

If I wanted to run this command here is what I would enter

```
bash accounts_parse.sh Admin
```

The error I get is

```
command not found
```

Thank you all for your help and I will clarify if my explanation is sub par or more information is needed.

Comment: Use the `--query` option to specify a JMESPath expression to filter the data instead of running `jq` after the fact. `aws iam --query '.Groups[].GroupName'`.

Comment: Why call `list-groups` first at all? Why not just call `get-group` right away and check if you get an empty list or not?

Comment: I am trying to automate this process for future use. I want to be able to provide the group name and just get printed a list of users that belong to that group. I would do it manually but, I have to do it over 18 accounts.

Answer (score 2):

> `if ${1} == $list_groups;`

This isn't how if statements in bash (and other POSIX shells) work.

The word that comes after `if` is a *command* to execute, and its exit status is evaluated, and if it's 0 the if-branch is taken.

That explains your "command not found" - it's trying to execute `${1}` as a command, and you don't have an "Admin" command.

Use either

```
if [ "${1}" = "$list_groups" ]
```

or

```
if [[ "${1}" = "$list_groups" ]]
```

the latter is a bashism (with some improvements) and won't work in other otherwise compatible shells. "==" is also available as a bash extension but entirely equivalent to "=", so I'd advise to just use that.

What's important is that the `[` is a *command* (typically a builtin, also accessible as "test"). It's not a special bit of syntax but a thing that is executed with arguments and returns a status. (`[[` has some special handling and is more syntax-y, but conceptually it's still "a thing to execute")

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read` builtin in `bash`:

```
read user _ < <(aws iam list-groups --output json | jq -r .'Groups[] | .GroupName' --output json)

if [[ $user == $1 ]]; then
   echo aws iam get-group --group-name $1 --output json
else 
   echo 'sorry'
fi
```

`read user _` will read first word from input into variable `user` and ignore remaining.

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I am getting the error that the command I entered is not found. Meaning when I run bash accounts_parse.sh <argument here> it is not finding my input.

Comment: Other than #!/bin/bash no I do not. Now it is not erroring out but, it is not finding my arg input ever.

Comment: Can you run your script with `bash -x accounts_parse.sh Admin` and check output.

Comment: + list_groups=
+ '[' Administrators = '' ']'
+ echo sorry
sorry

Comment: + read user _
++ aws iam list-groups --output json
++ jq -r '.Groups[] | .GroupName' --output json
jq: Unknown option --output
Use jq --help for help with command-line options,
or see the jq manpage, or online docs  at https://stedolan.github.io/jq
+ [[ '' == Administrators ]]
+ echo sorry
sorry

Comment: That means your `aws iam list-groups --output json | jq -r .'Groups[] | .GroupName' --output json` command line is giving error. May be you meant `aws iam list-groups --output json | jq -r .'Groups[] | .GroupName'` only?